# Getting Lookup Values Sharepoint Workflow 2013

Tags: designer-workflow, workflow-variable

I'm having problems getting the values from a lookup field and then store in a variable

Code:

```
Set Variable: v_related_requirement_intID to Current Item:Release
```

Error:

> An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the workflow instance. Exception details: System.InvalidCastException: The value 'Value' cannot be read as type 'Int32'. at Microsoft.Activities.GetDynamicValueProperty`1.CheckedRead(String propertyName, DynamicItem value)

Is there any way I could get the index value of the lookup field?

Answer (score 1):

Follow below steps

1.Data Source: instead of Current Item, select the List by name

2.Field: Your look up column

3.Return Field as: Lookup Value

4.Field: ID

5.Value: Current Item:ID

Answer (score 0):

Hope this link will help you. 
[Handling Lookup Columns in a SharePoint Designer Workflow](http://www.sharepointassist.com/2009/05/09/handling-lookup-columns-in-a-sharepoint-designer-workflow/)